# Fit regression lines of 500 samples of N=50 onto one sample plot in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I need to get 500 samples of N=50 each and draw a simple linear regression model with X1 as VI and y as DV on each sample. Then, I have to plot all of these samples' predictions on one previous sample dataframe, which I've called sample.dat.

This is my code so far:

```
  geom_point(sample.dat, mapping = aes(x = X1, y = y)) +
  #geom_line(data = lm.fit.dat, aes(y = true.y.fit), color = "blue") +
  theme_bw()


    for(i in 1:500){
  df = linear.dat[sample(1:nrow(linear.dat), size = 50),]
  g = p + geom_smooth(method = lm, data=df, color="red", size=0.5, alpha = 0) +
  geom_line(data = lm.fit.dat, aes(y = true.y.fit), color = "blue")  
}
    plot(g)
```

And this is my output:
[image: Output]

As you see, I only have 1 red line when I want 500 red lines of the 500 samples.

Comment: What does `linear_dat` look like?

Comment: See the "Possible model fits" section here for a tutorial on how to do this using the tidymodels framework: https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/statistics/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem is that in the loop you're adding the new line to `p`, but `g` isn't accumulating the lines.  At the end of the loop, `g` will only have the most recently generated line.  To accumulate the lines you have to do `g <- g+ ...` - you have to add the current line to all of the previous lines.   Something like this should work:

```
g <- ggplot(sample.dat, mapping = aes(x = X1, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()


for(i in 1:500){
  df = linear.dat[sample(1:nrow(linear.dat), size = 50),]
  g = g + 
    geom_smooth(method = lm, data=df, color="red", size=0.5, alpha = 0) 

}
plot(g)
```

[image]